puedo tener un operador dentro de una variable para poder realizar los calculos en una sola linea? en javascript

Declaro mis variables y operadores que aun no me funaciona.
     let operador = [+,-,/,*];
     let num1=3;
     let num2=3;
     let opc=1


llamo la funcion.
     calculadora(operador,num1,num2);



3.cree la funcion de calculadora.
        function calculadora(operador,num1,num2)
        {
        resultado=num1 operador num2;
        console.log(resultado);
        }


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Podrias si usas eval, lo cual es una idea espantosa...

This question is similar to: Se puede almacenar un operador(+,-,*,/) en una variable?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Otra opción que puedes tener en cuenta es utilizar la función eval() de JavaScript que permite interpretar un string como si fuera una sentencia de código.
let operadores = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

function calculadora(operador, num1, num2) {
    let resultado = eval(`${num1} ${operador} ${num2}`) // Uso de eval()
    console.log(resultado); 
}

let num1 = 3
let num2 = 3

calculadora(operadores[0], num1, num2) // Suma = 6 
calculadora(operadores[1], num1, num2) // Resta = 0 
calculadora(operadores[2], num1, num2) // Multiplicación = 9 
calculadora(operadores[3], num1, num2) // División = 1


Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:
let operadores = ['+', '-', '/', '*'];
let num1 = 3;
let num2 = 3;
let opc = 1;

calculadora(operadores, num1, num2, opc);

function calculadora(operadores, num1, num2, opc) {
    let operador = operadores[opc];
    let resultado;
    
    switch (operador) {
        case '+':
            resultado = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            resultado = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case '/':
            resultado = num1 / num2;
            break;
        case '*':
            resultado = num1 * num2;
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Operador no válido');
            return;
    }
    
    console.log(resultado);
}


Muchas Gracias A tu respuesta :), mi cuestion seria reducir la cantidad de linea de codigo. saludos

@GustavoVeraBogado yo te preguntaria.. porque???

Mas que nada para entender y reprogramar lo que esta hecho.
